# Resolving Coproduct type classes fails for obscure reasons

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm putting together a small serialization library for Scala on Android ([Parcelable](https://github.com/Taig/Parcelable/tree/develop)). But I keep struggling with resolving Coproduct related type classes that appear to fail depending on file names (?).

I first encountered the issue when I was writing the [tests](https://github.com/Taig/Parcelable/tree/develop/src/test/scala/test/io/taig/android). There is a simple file `Animal.scala` that contains a sealed trait hierarchy. The tests compile fine, and everything is working as intended, but as soon as I change the file name to `ZAnimal.scala`, for instance, the test suite fails to compile because Coproduct type class instances cannot be resolved any more.

This issue is exclusive for Coproduct type classes, case class related type classes don't break.

Unfortunately, this is also affecting projects that depend on the library where ADTs in `.widget` fail to resolve. Moving them to `.aaa` fixes the issue.

I'm afraid this might be caused by the underlying macro code and the compiler failing to discover certain types soon enough (maybe related to [scalamacros/paradise#14](https://github.com/scalamacros/paradise/issues/14)?). But I'd definitely prefer if it was a mistake in my library code.

Edit: I've put together a [small sample project](https://github.com/Taig/CoproductFailure/) that illustrates the issue more precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miles Sabin explained on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/milessabin/shapeless?at=56702bea187e75ea0e48bce1) that this related to [SI-7047](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7046).

> You're seeing this compiler bug (which affects all attempts to enumerate all subclasses, macro based or otherwise): https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7046
>
> If you put your ADT in a source file which will be compiled before the code that needs to enumerate its subclasses you should be OK.
>
> That's usually satisfied by the ADT being in a separate module.
>
> Lexicographic ordering of source file name has an effect on compilation order ... in particular, `Animal.scala` will be compiled before `ZAnimal.scala`.

A safe way to avoid this issue is to move the affected code into a separate submodule. This way the compiler has discovered all types when resolving type classes in the consuming module.